# Program does not terminated properly convert binary to decimal

Tags: arrays, c, queue, break

I write a c program to convert a binary number to a decimal number.

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int q[6],f,r;

int main()
   {
       int a,v,i,m,sum=0;
       f=r=-1;
       for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
          {
               scanf("%d",&v);
               if (v==1 || v==0){
               addq(v);
          }
          else{
                  printf("wrong input")
                  break;
              }
 }
  for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
      {
           a=delq();
           m=pow(2,i);
           sum=sum+a*m;
      }
      printf("DECIMAL NO.IS:%d",sum);
      return 0;
}

addq(int ele)
   {
       if(r==5)
       printf("QUEUE FULL");
   else
      {
          r++;
         q[r]=ele;
         if(f==-1)
         f=0;
     }
 }

delq()
{
   int ele;
   if(f==-1)
   printf("QUEUE EMPTY");
else
   {
      ele=q[f];
      if(f==r)
      f=r=-1;
      else
      f++;
      return(ele);
  }
}
```

If I enter input other than 0 or 1 it shows me wrong put but the program did not terminated full.

This the [image: output] output that I get. It not only shows the wrong output like 117 but also does not terminated.

Output:

1
0
1
5
Wrong input Queue EmptyQueue EmptyQueue EmptyDecimal NO IS: 117

What should I do to terminate the program?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please copy&paste the output to the question **as text**. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10622916 The code in the question cannot be compiled. You should fix the errors and warnings. Indenting the code properly will also help us to understand your code.

Comment: `break;` statement terminates the loop (in your program, 1st for loop). to exit program, use `exit(0)`

Comment: @vanisk Yes, Thank you. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` statement terminates the loop (in your program, 1st 'for loop') not the program.

To exit program, use `exit(0)`